# CSS selector for immediately succeeding child element

Tags: jquery, css

Two simple HTML examples:

```
<p>
  <i>Some text</i>
</p>

<p>Here's a paragraph that has <i>some text</i>, and then some more</p>
```

When using CSS, this selects the `<i>`'s in both cases:

```
p > i {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

`>` targets every `<i>` within every `<p>`.

What I'm looking for is a way to only target the `<i>`'s that immediately follow upon the `<p>`, in other words, that targets the `<i>` in the first example but not in the second. Kind of in a way that `+` selects adjacent siblings, but for adjacent children. Is this possible?

I looked into jQuery's `only-child` selector, but this also targets the `<i>`'s in both examples, since the text (*"here's a paragraph..."*) isn't considered a child.

Comment: Not possible with CSS since text nodes are essentially invisible to CSS. They do not count as elements.

Comment: There is ways to do this in jQuery/JS using textNode traversal and `filter()` etc, but it gets very ugly, very quickly. Is there no way you can amend the HTML?

Comment: Do you need it for this specific lines of code only or you need something which will be used across the whole page?

Comment: Are you asking for a selector that will ignore a tag if there's any text before it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this work using CSS but using javascript/jquery you can select target element as shown in bottom.

Select all `i` element and use `.filter()` to filtering selected elements. In filter callback check previous text of `i` using [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) property.

```js
$("p > i").filter(function(){
  return this.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim() == "";
}).css("border", "1px solid red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <i>Some text</i>
</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph that has <i>some text</i>, and then some more</p>
<p>
  <i>Some text</i>
</p>
<p>text <i>some text</i>, text</p>
```

Comment: Good approach. Note that you could improve it slightly by using `p > i` to avoid selecting irrelevant grandchild `i` elements.

Comment: Curiosity: @RoryMcCrossan if you know the answer, why don't you just post it?

Comment: @Matt I was in the process of writing an answer which was the inverse of this when this popped up, which is better. To be honest I was in two minds whether to answer at all, as frankly none of these are workable solutions in a production system. If I was the OP I would be looking in to changing the HTML.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your explanation @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain javaScript or jQuery. Since you tagged jQuery in your question i made a solution with it. See below.

I made the solution using index. To be sure i always get the first item, i used `trim()` to delete the whitespaces because

```
<p>
  <i>sometext</i>
</p>
```

would make `<i>` to have index of `3` instead of `0`. That's why you need trim().

Then you just do what you want with that `i` tag. I added a class and styled it in CSS.

```js
const paragraph = $("p");
const i = $('p > i')
$(paragraph).each(function() {
  const index = $(this).html().trim().indexOf('<i>');
  index === 0 ? $(this).find(i).addClass('change-me') : ''
})
```

```css
i.change-me {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <i>Some text</i>
</p>

<p>Here's a paragraph that has <i>some text</i>, and then some more</p>
```